# Apahce MPM ITK dropped connections

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I am currently using Apache MPM ITK on a dedicated Mac Mini server to allow Apache to run under multiple user accounts for different virtual hosts. I'm running into an issue that about 1-2% of the time, when I refresh a page I'll get a "The server dropped the connection" error. This only happens with the module installed and active. I'm wondering if anybody has experienced this or has insight as to how I can track down the issue.